# PHP - join equal arrays and add count of arrays joined

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have a task on my Laravel project that runs every day and check for expiration on some coupons. If they expire that day, I add them as array to the user table to display them on the admin panel. Problem is, client wants them to be shown joined if they share date and price properties and I'm having some trouble finding the appropriate way to do this. Let me explain:

```
        $coupons = Coupon::where([['date_end', date('Y-m-d')], ['status', '!=', 0]])->get();

        foreach ($coupons as $key => $coupon) 
        {
            $user = User::where('id', $coupon->user_id)->first();

            $coupon->status = Coupon::EXPIRED;
            $coupon->save();

            if ($user->expired_coupons == NULL) 
            {
                $coupons_expired = [];
            }
            else
            {
                $coupons_expired = json_decode($user->expired_coupons);
            }

            $last_coupon_expired['date'] = $coupon->date_end;
            $last_coupon_expired['quantity'] = 1;
            $last_coupon_expired['price'] = $coupon->voucher->available->price_per_meal;

            $coupons_expired[] = $last_coupon_expired;
            $user->expired_coupons = $coupons_expired;
            $user->save();
        }
```

And I'll get something like this in the db:

```
[{
    "date": "2020-05-24",
    "quantity": 1,
    "price": 5
}, {
    "date": "2020-05-24",
    "quantity": 1,
    "price": 5
}, {
    "date": "2020-05-24",
    "quantity": 1,
    "price": 10
}, {
    "date": "2020-05-23",
    "quantity": 1,
    "price": 5
}]
```

Which looks like this in my admin panel:
[image: Panel picture]

And in this case, the way I'd want it to show would be:
- 2020-05-24 || 2 || 5
- 2020-05-24 || 1 || 10
- 2020-05-23 || 1 || 5

If I didn't need the quantity I could just get rid of the arrays that are exactly equal, but everything I tried to get the thing working as I want to has failed. Any pointers? Thanks.

Comment: Could you enrich the original post with the definitions of your tables and perhaps the models as well as their relationships?

Answer (score 0):

If it is possible to share the data what you have got `$coupons` variable. But i tried to solve the problem by grouping the date and price. May be there need to more improvement.

```
$coupons = Coupon::where([['date_end', date('Y-m-d')], ['status', '!=', 0]])->get();
$coupons_expired = [];   
foreach ($coupons as $key => $coupon)
{
    $user = User::where('id', $coupon->user_id)->first();

    $coupon->status = Coupon::EXPIRED;
    $coupon->save();

    if ($user->expired_coupons == NULL)
    {
        $coupons_expired = [];
    }
    else
    {
        $coupons_expired = json_decode($user->expired_coupons);
    }

    if (isset($coupons_expired[$coupon->date_end][$coupon->voucher->available->price_per_meal])) {
        $coupons_expired[$coupon->date_end][$coupon->voucher->available->price_per_meal]['quantity']++;
    } else {
        $coupons_expired[$coupon->date_end][] = [
            $coupon->voucher->available->price_per_meal => [
                'data' => $coupon->date_end,
                'quantity' => 1,
                'price' => $coupon->voucher->available->price_per_meal   
            ]
        ];
    }

    $user->expired_coupons = $coupons_expired;
    $user->save();
}

$mappedData = [];

foreach ($coupons_expired as $data => $dateGroups) {
    foreach ($dateGroups as $qty => $coupon) {
        $mappedData[] = $coupon;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it. I finally came up with my own (also need a lot of improvement) solution. Ill paste it.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this solution that, for now, meets my needs. Since the date will always be the same for the coupons that expire (being a daily task) I just create an array with all the prices and the amount of times they appear, and then iterate it to make the final array of coupons expired joined by date and price.

```
            foreach ($coupons as $key => $coupon) 
            {
                $coupon->status = Coupon::EXPIRED;
                $coupon->save();

                $expired_coupon_price['price'] = (string)$coupon->voucher->available->price_per_meal;

                $expired_coupons_prices[] = $expired_coupon_price;
            }        

            $array_prices_unique = array_count_values(array_column($expired_coupons_prices, 'price'));

            foreach ($array_prices_unique as $key => $price) 
            {                
                $last_coupon_expired['date'] = date('Y-m-d');
                $last_coupon_expired['quantity'] = $price;
                $last_coupon_expired['price'] = (float) key($array_prices_unique);

                $coupons_expired_today[] = $last_coupon_expired;
                next($array_prices_unique);
            }

            if ($user->expired_coupons == NULL) 
            {
                $coupons_expired_from_user = [];
            }
            else
            {
                $coupons_expired_from_user = json_decode($user->expired_coupons);
            }

            $user->expired_coupons = array_merge($coupons_expired_from_user,$coupons_expired_today);
            $user->save();
        }
```